# question on multiprocessing and static variables in C

Tags: c, variables, static

I am having some problem with a C project.
The situation is the following:

1. I have a main file which includes a file .h with static variables and another C file with all the functions (this also includes the file .h).
2. If I run the main it works fine, but I would like to run different instances on different shells so that I can exchange messages.

The problem is that both the processes are allocating the static variables in the same location of memory, so the operations done by the second instance will overwrite the ones of the first instance.

Hope I was clear, I'm not very proficient in C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use a static variable to exchange data between two processes. The addresses you are seeing are very likely to be [virtual](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory), i.e. each process has its own address space, so although an address might look identical, it's really mapped to different RAM.

You need a real [inter-process communication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) (IPC) solution, such as files, shared memory, pipes, sockets, or similar approach.

Comment: To be clear: Static variables are not shared between processes. They are just shared between all libraries and object files *linked* to the same process.

Answer (score 0):

That isn't so. Each process gets its own completely separate address space, so they cannot overwrite each other.